# Better etiquette; If x == True: | If x:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Which should i be using in my code?

```
If x == True:
  print('x is True')
```

or

```
If x:
  print('x is True')
```

which one should i be using?

Comment: they are not precisely equivalent, but the latter is the idiomatic way to do it

Comment: Both are acceptable but it's better to use appropriate convention like `If x == True`

Comment: @mhhabib: Heck no. `== True` is discouraged, inefficient, and often outright wrong.

Comment: @mhhabib that is *not* the convention

Comment: if `x` is not a boolean value, there may be differences between both codes. `x = 42` will give different outputs